# Word for excessive positive interest that becomes a burden?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example: Josh is so interested in mathematics that he sits for hours and hours working on the problems. He forgets to eat. He lost weight, he doesn't clean the house and doesn't even notice what's going on because all he wants to do is his work.

There is a slang expression

> workaholic

that doesn't include the negative side-effects of obsessive work with something that actually produces results but also has very negative side-effects.

Example: Henry likes computer programming so much that software development is all he wants to do. He has no social life and he speaks of advanced computer science with non-technicians so that he doesn't get understood. It takes a Ph D in computer science to understand what Henry is talking about and he is only 14 years old.

Comment: Just _obsession_ would probably work.

Comment: At first I thought you might be describing a form of *obsessive-compulsive disorder,* a form of mental illness that has its own chapter in the DSM-V; however, after reading a little more about it, this is something quite different. I recall the (unconfirmed) story that Einstein's wife painted their front door red because Albert would walk into the first house that looked similar to his, sit down and continue working.

Comment: *too much of a good thing*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[Workalcholic](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/workaholic)*** does convey the idea of an obsessive dedication to work:

(Psychology):

> - a person obsessively addicted to work

(Collins Dictionary)

> - A [workaholic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workaholic) is a person who works compulsively. There is no generally accepted medical definition of such a condition, although ***some forms of stress, impulse control disorder, obsessive-compulsive personality disorder, and obsessive-compulsive disorder can be work-related.***

Origin of the term:

> - The word itself is a portmanteau word composed of work and alcoholic. Its first known appearance, according to the Oxford English Dictionary, came in ***Canada in the Toronto Daily Star of 5 April 1947, page 6, with a punning allusion to Alcoholics Anonymous:***
>
>   - *If you are cursed with an unconquerable craving for work, call Workaholics Synonymous, and a reformed worker will aid you back to happy idleness.*

(Wikipedia)

also ***[Stakhanovite](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/Stakhanovite):***

> - An exceptionally hard-working or zealous person:

(ODO)